# jQuery on function on ul and ul inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure for a nav

```
<ul class="parentul">
     <li class="has-dropdown">
           <a href="">Link title<span class="desc">Link desc</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">    
                <li class="title back">
                    <h5><a href="#">Back</a></h5>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h5><a href="#">Option 1</a></h5>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h5><a href="#">Option 2</a></h5>
                 </li>
           </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul > li.has-dropdown').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('moved');
    $('.parentul').animate({
        left: "-100%"
    });

}); 

$('ul > li.has-dropdown.moved > ul > li.back').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.has-dropdown').removeClass('moved');
    $('.parentul').animate({
        left: "0"
    });
});
```

I have an on click function for the li.has-dropdown that slides it out of view and brings the child ul into view, however I want the child li.back to initiate it sliding back and bringing the original nav into view.

My problem is that, where the child ul is inside the li.has-dropdown, clicking any link initiates the behaviour of the original transition.

What is the best way to click on one of the li.has-dropdown to slide the child ul into view, and have the li.back in the child ul slide it back to how it was?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you add a fiddle.

Comment: Use  http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ with `li.back`

Comment: your explanation is not very helpful. please include JS example (what you have done) and/or a 


[.-={jsfiddle}=-.](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @j08691 jQuery attached

Comment: @Rider jQuery attached

Comment: @MrFirthy learn using jsfiddle, this will cost you some effort to learn, but will safe time to those, who can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in `li.back` event handler.

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Code

```
$('ul > li.has-dropdown.moved > ul > li.back').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.has-dropdown').removeClass('moved');
    $('.parentul').animate({
        left: "0"
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, forgot about this. Thanks for the quick response!